# What is the proper way to use If conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, use-effect

I am trying to set auto index in React like below:
You can think, now the total index of my data 5. It can be changed at any time.

```js
const Carousel = props => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const indexSetter = () => {
    if (index === data.length - 1) {
      setIndex(0)
    } else {
      setIndex(index + 1)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(indexSetter, 5000);
  })
  const data = [{
    title: 'This is the first time',
    description: 'We are able OH my god this first theme',
    link: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518583396317-c4e34ac7794b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'
  },
  {
    title: 'This is the Second time',
    description: 'We are able 1 Ke ane tomar katha ami janina',
    link: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559237705-a097e76c10c9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'
  },
  {
    title: 'This is the Third time',
    description: 'We are able 1 youj ar eno en Able ot',
    link: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507144894800-1842d020ae69?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'
  },
  {
    title: 'This is the Fourth time',
    description: 'We are able 1 jdfkjdk fjdlfdjdlk dkjdlkdj',
    link: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573008233527-59ca89650f3b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'
  },
  {
    title: 'This is the Sixth time',
    description: 'We are able kjk dkfjdkl dsie kdfjkd',
    link: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562979314-bee7453e911c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'
  },
  ]


  return (
    <div className={classes.Carousel}>
      <CarItem
        link={data[index].link}
        title={data[index].title}
        description={data[index].description}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
export default Carousel;
```

But after rounding total length, it crashes. It doesn't set index again from 0;
I searched on google. I don't understand what mistake I have done.
Since I am new in coding, Don't be bothered by my boring question.
**Update: I have added my full component. Now doesn't crash. After the first round, index changes so faster than my given time.**

Comment: On that crash, there was probably an error message. That usually gives a hint. Can you share it?

Comment: If you’re using index in the interval is needs to be in the use effect’s dependency array.

Comment: According to MDN, a const requires a legal identifier which is case-sensitive and can contain Unicode letters, $, _, and digits (0-9), but may not start with a digit.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing it shows compile error!

Comment: @GKJahid *what* compile error? What does it say exactly

Comment: @VLAZ now it doesn't crash, index change so fast than my given time. I have updated my full component.